# How to show just a single result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script I am working on that retrieves results based on the first letter of the title. I have links A-Z that you can click and it will show all the results starting with that letter. My problem is I am trying to display data from table1 and display an image for that result if one exists in table2, if not then it will only show the result data from table1.

My script seems to be working fine but if more than one image exists in table 2 that matches the link_id in table 1 then it will show the result more than once.
I am trying to figure out a way to only pull 1 image from table2 even if more exist that equal the link_id in table1. I made a column called default_image in table 2 and every link_id that has multiple images has 1 of the images set to 1 as default and all other images set to 0.

How can I show the results that only have a default image or no image at all "meaning if there is no image available in table2 linked to the link_id in table1 then the result text from table 1 will still show".

Here is what I am doing.

```
$letter = $_GET['letter'];
$sql = "
select 
    s.link_id, 
    s.title, 
    i.media_id, 
    i.link_id, 
    i.media_link,
    i.title 
from table1 as s 
LEFT JOIN images as i on (i.link_id = s.link_id) 
where s.title like '$letter%' 
and s.def = i.title";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($CONF['debug']?("ERROR: mysql query failed: ".mysql_error()):"ERROR: Please try later");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $letter = $_GET['letter'];
    //echoing all data here
}
```

Just to try to be as clear as possible. I am basically trying to query the database and display the table1 data and table2 "images" data if any images exists, if not just display table1 data and make sure that I only display the default image if more than one image exists.

Anyone have any ideas on what to do?
Thanks.

EDIT:
Fixed using GROUP BY. Thank you who ever suggested it and deleted their comment. I totally forgot about group by.

Comment: Your script is open to an SQL injection attack.  Don't use data from $_GET or $_POST without first validating that it's safe to use.  Use mysql_real_escape_string or learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for he heads up but I know this. I was just trying to get it to work on localhost. If I use it for production i will make sure to validate everything.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select 
s.link_id, 
s.title, 
i.media_id, 
i.link_id, 
i.media_link,
i.title 
from table1 as s 
LEFT JOIN images as i on (i.link_id = s.link_id) 
where s.title like '$letter%' 
and s.def = i.title
order by i.default_image DESC
limit 1
```

Just you need to sort descending by default_image field (so non empty rows will be at the top) and limit your query by 1, so you take only first row (if there are more than one).